# Car making loud PAT sound and also sometimes making quiet pss sound when shifting gears sometimes

Tags: noise, transmission, clutch, manual-transmission, clutch-cable

i have 2000 FIAT Siena 1.4el 5 speed manual and its done only 105000km (around 60000 miles) in 23 years ever since we bought it in late 1999 , it has cable operated clutch and sometimes i hear really loud PAT like sound when shifting. Its not like a grinding or crunching or whining noise, there is just a loud PAT like sound. I think it has happened when downshifting from 4 to 3 and when shifting into second from first, so i have a feeling its something to do with clutch maybe? Also the quieter pss sound im talking about kinda sounds like you know when you disconnect the air hose after inflating a football ball or a tire and you hear a pss sound after disconnecting the hose its kinda like that but it also happens when shifting like the PAT sound. Also i first noticed this 2 weeks ago and has only happened 3 times and the gears are all fine the synchros also work fine still and i know the clutch on it is really old i think it still has same clutch from 1999 when my dad first bought the car brand new so could this sound be coming from the clutch?

Comment: It would be very hard to make a diagnosis with your description. A video with quality sound of what you're talking about might go a long way. It could very well be the clutch. The "pss" sound might be a throw out bearing. The Fiat is 23 years old, but with only 60k miles on it, I wouldn't think the clutch would be bad, but that's also dependent upon how the vehicle is driven and whether or not the clutch is "ridden" (ie: "ride the clutch"  or having your foot on the clutch pedal during normal driving).

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will try to record the sound but its really weird it happens very rarely so im not sure if i can catch it but i ll try

Comment: What does the word "PAT" mean?

Comment: it means nothing, it is how the sound sounds like

Comment: I found the problem if anybody is still wondering. Apperantly the welds between cat and first muffler were damaged because today they blew out completely. Pat sound was coming from the damaged weld letting loud exhaust out